# Java: Literal percent sign in printf statement

Tags: java, printf, escaping

I'm trying to add an actual percent sign into a printf statement in Java and I'm getting the error:

```
lab1.java:166: illegal escape character
                System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%1.2f\%\t%1.2f\%\n",ID,pattern,support,confidence);
                                                 ^
lab1.java:166: illegal escape character
                System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%1.2f\%\t%1.2f\%\n",ID,pattern,support,confidence);
                                                          ^
2 errors
```

I can't figure out how to put an actual percent sign into my printf? I thought using \% to escape it would work, but it isn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

The percent sign is escaped using a percent sign:

```
System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%1.2f%%\t%1.2f%%\n",ID,pattern,support,confidence);
```

The [complete syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) can be accessed in [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/). This particular information is in the section `Conversions` of the first link.

The reason the compiler is generating an error is that only a limited amount of [characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) may follow a backslash. `%` is not a valid character.

Answer (score 124):

Escaped percent sign is double percent (%%):

```
System.out.printf("2 out of 10 is %d%%", 20);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use StringEscapeUtils from Apache Commons Logging utility or escape manually using code for each character.

Comment: Should use `StringEscapeUtils` from `commons-text`, since the one from `commons-lang3` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Check below Code ---

```
public class Printer {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.printf("2 out of 10 is %d%%", 20);
   }
}
```