# How to have multiple formats in a single text field in jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a text field that displays 3 parameters with different formats. It has a Date value, a BigDecimal value and a value that has to be displayed using percentage display.

Can I use a single text field for this or do I have to use one text field for each to have the correct format for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few approaches, presuming it is one of the three parameters you want to display in the same location:

- Use three different fields and a `PrintWhenExpression` for each parameter.
- Convert the different fields to a single String variable, with appropriate formatting, and then a single field for that variable value.

The second approach is probably the most applicable for your task. For the conversions, look at:

- [BigDecimal.toString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)
- [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [String.sprintf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

See also:

[Java: Literal percent sign in printf statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708444/java-literal-percent-sign-in-printf-statement)