# Nested If/Else Statements 

Tags: java, if-statement, formatexception

Sorry to be editing this once again, but rather than make another post, I thought I would ask it here.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO code application logic here

char response = 0;
double grossAnnualIncome = 0.0;
double annualTuition = 0.0;
double annualCharity = 0.0;
double homeMortgage = 0.0;
double healthCredit = 0.0;
double annualAfterTaxes = 0.0;
double monthlyAfterTaxes = 0.0;
double taxAt17 = 0.0;
double taxableIncome = 0.0;
double ans1 = 0.0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.printf( "Please enter your gross annual income or 0 for none: " );
grossAnnualIncome = input.nextDouble();

if( grossAnnualIncome > 0 )
    {
    System.out.printf( "Please enter your annual tuition and expenses for higher education or 0 for none: ");
    annualTuition = input.nextDouble();

 System.out.printf( "Please enter your annual charitable contributions or 0 for none: ");
    annualCharity = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.printf( "Please enter the annual interest paid for your home mortgage or 0 for none: ");
    homeMortgage = input.nextDouble();
    input.nextLine();

    System.out.printf( "Did you purchase health insurance through your employer or outside the workplace?"
              + " Enter 'Y' or 'N': ");
response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);


        if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'Y' )
        {
        System.out.printf( "Are you filing as a family?  Enter 'Y' or 'N': ");
        response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

            if ( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'Y' )
            {
            healthCredit = 3500;
            }
        else
        {

        if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'N' )
            {
                System.out.printf( "Are you filing as single?  Enter 'Y' or 'N': ");
                response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            }
                    if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'Y')
                    {
                    healthCredit = 2000;
                    }

        }

        }
        else
        {
        healthCredit = 0;
        }

    taxableIncome = grossAnnualIncome - homeMortgage - annualTuition - annualCharity - healthCredit;
        taxAt17 = taxableIncome * .17;
        annualAfterTaxes = grossAnnualIncome - taxAt17;
        monthlyAfterTaxes = annualAfterTaxes / 12;
        ans1 = homeMortgage + annualTuition + annualCharity + healthCredit;

    System.out.printf( "\nYOUR TAXES\n\n"
                    + "Gross Annual Income: %,.0f\n\n"
                    + "Deductions: \n"
                    + "\tHigher Education: %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tCharitable Contributions: %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tHome Mortgage Interest: %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tHealth Insurance Tax Credit: %,.0f\n\n"
                    + "Tax at 17%%: %,.0f\n"
                    + "Annual Income After Taxes: %,.0f\n"
                    + "Monthly Income After Taxes: %,.0f", grossAnnualIncome, annualTuition, annualCharity,
                       homeMortgage, healthCredit, taxAt17, annualAfterTaxes, monthlyAfterTaxes);


}

  if( grossAnnualIncome <= 0 )
  {
  System.out.printf( "You earned no income so you owe no taxes!" );
  }

   System.exit(0);
  }

}
```

Both of my outputs are correct, but I am having trouble with my last one.

My last output needs to read "YOU OWE $0.00 IN TAXES!"

When I code:

```
if (grossAnnualIncome <= ans1)
{
System.out.printf( "YOU OWE $0.00 IN TAXES!" );
}
```

It shows everything from grossAnnualIncome > 0 output.

Comment: print the input that you are giving... also at which line you are getting this exception??

Comment: I'm not sure which line, the above snippet is exactly what the exception error posted.

As for my input:
Please enter your gross annual income or 0 for none: 25000
Please enter your annual tuition and expenses for higher education or 0 for none: 2500
Please enter your annual charitable contributions or 0 for none: 100
Please enter the annual interest paid for your home mortgage or 0 for none: 0
Did you purchase health insurance through your employer or outside the workplace?Enter 'Y' or 'N': y
Are you filing as a family?  Enter 'Y' or 'N': y

Then I get error message.

Comment: for family press N and tell me what you get...

Comment: also change `monthlyAfterTaxes = annualAfterTaxes / 12;` to `monthlyAfterTaxes = (double) annualAfterTaxes / 12;` and let me know what you get...

Comment: Ok, if I press N for family I get the same exception error as above.

Comment: ok... did you did above change??

Comment: Yes, I casted annualAfterTaxes /12 as a double. The exception happens right after I press Y or N to Family Health Insurance.

Comment: give me some time.... I am looking into it...

Comment: the problem is when you are printing the values at the end... Please look at it...

Comment: Yeah, I have been trying to figure it out. I've edited my post to where I think I narrowed down the exception error. I just haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: please read [this](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/java-double-question/12458.html). Hope it will solve your problem...

Comment: Thank you for spending your time trying to help me. I am quite the novice, and this was my biggest undertaking yet on my own. I got the hang of some things, and learned a little too! So thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java: Literal percent sign in printf statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708444/java-literal-percent-sign-in-printf-statement)

It probably has to do with the percent in 17%. It needs to be escaped which can be done with another %

```
17%%
```

Comment: I was able to fix the health insurance code, I had my brackets wrong. thanks for your help nonetheless! I will update my code with what I have.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I actually did not know that I needed another one there, so duly noted and thank you once again for your help!

Comment: I had issues with this once, formatting can be hard to understand :P