# Java printf fails : UnknownFormatConversionException

Tags: java, exception, printf

I am trying understand why one of my printf statements fail. #1 below is fine, but #2 fails with the exception at the end. What's causing this?

```
0       String LOCATION = "http://www.mywebsite.web/";
1       System.out.printf(" <img src=\"%sIMAGE.gif\">", LOCATION);   
2       System.out.printf(" <img src=\"%sIMAGE.gif\" width=\"25%\" height=\"25%\" border=0>", LOCATION);

Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '"'
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2519)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2501)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2430)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:937)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:838)
    at MyCode.main(MyCode.java:292)
```

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: Escape character for % sign is %
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708444/java-literal-percent-sign-in-printf-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
String LOCATION = "http://www.mywebsite.web/";
System.out.printf(" <img src='%sIMAGE.gif'>", LOCATION);   
System.out.printf(" <img src='%sIMAGE.gif' width='25%%' height='25%%' border=0>", LOCATION);
```

I have replaced `"` with `'` ( **looks simplified** ) will work like **charm** as in `html` `"` or `'` do **great**.
For `%` , it should be `%%` as `%` is escaped with `%`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the percent sign. Since % is used as a format string. You can insert % as a literal preceding it with another percent... %%

```
System.out.printf(" <img src=\"%sIMAGE.gif\" width=\"25%%\" height=\"25%%\" border=0>", LOCATION);
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception says that `%"` is not a valid format specifier. You should escape your `%` sign in line 2:

```
System.out.printf(" <img src=\"%sIMAGE.gif\" width=\"25%%\" height=\"25%%\" border=0>", LOCATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%\"
```

Is not a valid printf field.