# Why is printf producing an compiler error?

Tags: java, printf

I'm trying to make program that shows the time of day and fraction of day that has passed which must use printf. I can't figure out why printf is producing this compiler error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.DuplicateFormatFlagsException: Flags = ' '
at java.util.Formatter$Flags.parse(Formatter.java:4140)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.flags(Formatter.java:2555)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2625)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2480)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2414)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:920)
at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:821)
at FractionOfDay.fractionOfDay(FractionOfDay.java:22)
at FractionOfDay.main(FractionOfDay.java:26)
```

Code:

```
public class FractionOfDay
{
   public static void fractionOfDay(int hour, int minute, int second, char ampm)
   {
      double fractionofday = hour/12 + minute/720 + second/43200 + ampm/2;
      if (ampm == 'A')
      {
         String ampmoutput = "AM";
      }
      else
      {
         String ampmoutput = "PM";
      }
      if (hour < 10)
      {
         String space = " ";
      }
      else
      {
         String space = "  ";
      }
      System.out.printf("%2d:%2ds%%s  %4f", hour,minute,"space","ampmoutput",fractionofday);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      fractionOfDay(7,15,0,'P');
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the compiler error?  What you're showing appears to be a runtime error.

Comment: Only thing looks weird in your code is `s%%s`. So that's the issue here.

Comment: As mentioned in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1708452/2317829 `%%` is how one escapes the percent sign when interpolating, so your syntax error is causing the interpolator to ignore it instead of have a `%` after your interpolated value (which as noted needs to be `%s`).

Answer (score 1):

First string you have `s%%s`   have to be `%s%s`

Comment: Thanks guys that solved the error, but now I have the issue of "space" and "ampmoutput" printing literally "space" and "ampmoutput" instead of what I assigned those strings to earlier in the code.                   Output is  7:15spaceampmoutput  40.000000 Should be 7:15  AM  40.000000 I tried removing the quotes it gave me the errors FractionOfDay.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.printf("%2d:%2d%s%s  %2f", hour, minute, space, ampmoutput,
                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable space
  location: class FractionOfDay

Answer (score 1):

I believe your format string is messed up.
Instead of s%%s you should use %s%s

Also, your space and ampmoutput should not be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `printf` statement is wrong cause

1. use of `s%%s` instead of `%s%s`
2. putting output variables in quotes `"space","ampmoutput"`

Change your `printf` statement to look like

```
System.out.printf("%2d:%2d%s%s  %4f", hour,minute,space,ampmoutput,fractionofday);
```

Answer (score -1):

The scope of your variables space and ampmoutput are within their own if block and can not be referenced from outside of the block. Try declare space and ampmoutput outside of the if statements and modify their values from inside the if statements.