# System.print.out if one integer is a multiple of the other

Tags: java

I am writing a program where 2 integers are inputted by user,then the program determines whether the first is a multiple of the second and prints the result.

Here is my code:

```
package assignmentsmodule1_exercise2.pkg16;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignmentsModule1_Exercise216 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number1;
        int number2;

        System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
        number1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
        number2 = input.nextInt();

        if (number1 % number2 == number1);
        System.out.printf("%d % %d%n", number1, number2);
    }

}
```

Every time I run the program an error message comes up.

Here is the error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatFlagsException: Flags = ' '
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkText(Formatter.java:3037)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2733)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2560)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at      assignmentsmodule1_exercise2.pkg16.AssignmentsModule1_Exercise216.main(AssignmentsModule1_Exercise216.java:34)
Java Result: 1
```

Is there anyone who can help me with my problem?

Comment: Shall we guess what the error message is, or will you tell us?  :-)

Comment: Notice the dangling `;` at the end of your `if`. I'm almost certain that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Dude there is a ; after your if condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

M is divisible by N when M % N == 0

Your line

```
if (number1 % number2 == number1);
```

should be

```
if (number1 % number2 == 0)
```

(Notice I removed the `;` mentioned by @Sotirios in his comment.

Also you need to escape the literal % in the following line

```
System.out.printf("%d % %d%n", number1, number2);
```

Should be

```
System.out.printf("%d %% %d%n", number1, number2);
```

Also, you have three placeholders but only two parameters.

Comment: I was assuming this but I didn't want to put as answer because I wasn't sure

Answer (score 0):

your printf statment has has unescapped % sign.
Your multipliciyt test is also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your printf needs to escape the '%' character:

```
System.out.printf("%d %% %d%n", number1, number2);
```

Just add an extra '%' to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't escaped your % character on your printf function. The % alone is not permitted, Java tries to combine it to the next space character. Use another % to escape ie. write %% instead.

**Source:**
[Java: Literal percent sign in printf statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708444/java-literal-percent-sign-in-printf-statement)