# Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'r'

Tags: java

Hello I am new to programming and am stuck and cannot figure this conversion exception out. I looked but could not find a similar one at least from what I know to search properly. This is my code. Does anyone see what I did wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonthlySalary
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    double regularSalary, hours, payRate, totalSalary;
    double overTime, hourlyPay;
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);   

    //regular hours
    System.out.print("How regular hours did you work this month? ");
    hours = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("How much do you get paid per hour? ");
    payRate = in.nextDouble();

    regularSalary = (payRate * hours);
    System.out.printf("Your monthly salary is $ %.2f\n", regularSalary);

    //overtime
    System.out.print("How many overtime hours did you work this month? ");
    overTime = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("How much is your hourly pay? ");
    hourlyPay = in.nextDouble();

    double tempoverTimePay = overTimeCalculator(hourlyPay, overTime);

    //total salary for the year
    totalSalary = ((tempoverTimePay + regularSalary) * 12);
    System.out.printf("This is how much you will make for the year if it continues at this rate: $ %.2f ", totalSalary);

    //salary plus raise
    System.out.printf("This is how much you will make if you get a 10% raise $ %.2f", ((totalSalary * .10) + totalSalary));

    //the man gets his cut
    if(totalSalary <= 13150)
      {
       System.out.printf("You will pay $ %.2f\n", (totalSalary * .10) + "in taxes.");
      }
    else
      if(totalSalary <= 50200)
      {   
       System.out.printf("You will pay $ %.2f\n", (totalSalary * .15) + "in taxes.");
      }
    else   
      if(totalSalary <= 129600)
         {
          System.out.printf("You will pay $ %.2f\n", (totalSalary * .25) + "in taxes.");
         }
    else
      if(totalSalary <= 209850)
      {   
       System.out.printf("You will pay $ %.2f\n", (totalSalary * .28) + "in taxes.");
      }
    else
      if(totalSalary <= 411500)
      {
       System.out.printf("You will pay $ %.2f\n", (totalSalary * .33) + "in taxes.");
      }
    else   
      if(totalSalary <= 439000)
      { 
       System.out.printf("You will pay $ %.2f\n", (totalSalary * .35) + "in taxes.");
      }
    else  
      if(totalSalary <= 439001)
        { 
         System.out.printf("You will pay $ %.2f\n", (totalSalary * .40) + "in taxes.");        
        }
   }

   //overtime method
   public static double overTimeCalculator(double declaredPayRate, double declaredOverTime)   
   {
    double overTimePay = ((declaredPayRate * 1.5) * declaredOverTime);
    System.out.printf("Your over time pay is $ %.2f\n", overTimePay);
    return overTimePay;
   }
}
```

Comment: The error seems to be in my if statement when it reads the print line throws format exception.

Comment: Jay, the problem has nothing to do with your if statement -- please see my answer. In the future you will want to post the full error message and indicate which line causes the message to appear.

Comment: You have over 5000 posts. I've googled and searched stack overflow but none that I saw seemed to be the same that I saw.

Comment: The solution is easily found in the Java API. `System.out` is a PrintStream object, and so this class will have the `printf(...)` method. That API entry will give you a link to the [Formatter API entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) and there you will find information on use of `%` in a format String.

Comment: Also I just found [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1708452/522444).

Comment: I think this is what you meant. 2nd week doing java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html

Comment: What I meant is in my answer below, no more and no less.

Answer (score 0):

Change `10% raise`

to: `10%% raise`

The printf is assuming that your `%` in `10%` is a format specifier when in fact it isn't, and so to "escape" the `%` within a printf statement, you have to double it.

For example:

```
System.out.printf("This is how much you will make if you get a 10%% raise $ %.2f", 
       ((totalSalary * .10) + totalSalary));
```

---

I just ran your code, and your exception is on the line that I indicated and is due to the problem that I have indicated above. Up to you how to proceed from here, but I'd recommend fixing the error that I've mentioned.  Then you've got other problems that will crop up once you've fixed this, including this line:

```
System.out.printf("You will pay $ %.2f\n", (totalSalary * .15)
                + "in taxes.");
```

which is not correct. The "in taxes should be in the format String and `\n` should be changed to `%n`:

```
System.out.printf("You will pay $ %.2f%n in taxes.", (totalSalary * .15));
```

Same for the similar code lines that follow.

Comment: Ok I made a few changes and got it working. I did as you said and I changed that and I took out the + "in taxes" and just reworded it and made it part of the "You will pay". Thank you for your help. Pretty amazing that you learned it on your own. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @Jay: Good, glad you've got it working. The key here is that you should look more critically at the error/exception messages as they'll usually tell you exactly what's wrong and **where**.

Comment: Yes I'm just learning how to decipher it. Although after a little while I imagine it becomes common sense. Using jGRASP IDE so it is pretty basic.