# String.format() error: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException

Tags: java

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier: &
at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.unknownFormatConversionException(Formatter.java:1399)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.checkFlags(Formatter.java:1336)
at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1442)
at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1081)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1554)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1528)
```

at this line of code:

```
query = String.format(GMAP_QUERY, location, location);
```

Variables:

```
private String location = "12.38484,55.43845";

static final String GMAP_QUERY = "staticmapcenter=%s&zoom=13&size=300x100&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:red%7C%s&style=feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off";
```

Why does it throw that exception? What does `Format specifier: &` mean?

Comment: "with 2 %s in it."... No, there is only one. `staticmapcenter=%s`

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. There is another one at `&markers=color:red%7C%s` at the end. Have edited my post now. SOrry @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape unwanted %. Otherwise String will take it as arguments (missing). 
To escape single (unrepeated) percent sign you need to add another percent character behind it ie. %%.

It is s worth looking at this:
[Java: Literal percent sign in printf statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708444/java-literal-percent-sign-in-printf-statement) and Java trails from Oracle https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a space in your URL (%20) `&maptype=roadmap%20` and (%7C) `&markers=color:red%7C` is just a vertical bar, which you already have  `&style=feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off`

So fix those, and use a URLEncoder to encode the string that you need to format.

```
String fmt = "staticmapcenter=%s&zoom=13&size=300x100&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red|%s&style=feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off";
String path = URLEncoder.encode(String.format(fmt, "s1", "s2"));
```

Which makes `staticmapcenter%3Ds1%26zoom%3D13%26size%3D300x100%26maptype%3Droadmap%26markers%3Dcolor%3Ared%7Cs2%26style%3Dfeature%3Apoi%7Celement%3Alabels%7Cvisibility%3Aoff`

---

But, you are looking for this instead probably.

```
String location = "12.38484,55.43845";
String fmt = "staticmap?center=%s&zoom=13&size=300x100&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red|%s&style=feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off";
String path = String.format(fmt, location, location);
System.out.print("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/" + path);
```

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=12.38484,55.43845&zoom=13&size=300x100&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red|12.38484,55.43845&style=feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the emphasized parts:

```
"staticmapcenter=%s&zoom=13&size=300x100&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:red%7C%s&style=feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off"
```

The `%`s used in the URL encoding are also parsed as formatters in `String.format`. They need to be escaped. The exception is complaining that it doesn't understand what `%20&` means.