# EditText format masks don't appear the % symbol

Tags: android, android-edittext, mask

I'm trying to make a camp the put de "%" result in an application.

The problem is that the Mask that I'm using its to simple to do that, so when I use, the numbers goes from 1 to 999 and the "%" doesn't appear to show too.

Someone can help me?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.github.rtoshiro.util.format.MaskFormatter;
import com.github.rtoshiro.util.format.SimpleMaskFormatter;
import com.github.rtoshiro.util.format.pattern.MaskPattern;
import com.github.rtoshiro.util.format.text.MaskTextWatcher;

public class ActivityForm extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText percentual;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_form);

        percentual = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentual_Id);
        SimpleMaskFormatter simpleMaskPercentual = new SimpleMaskFormatter( " NNN% " );
        MaskTextWatcher maskPercentual = new MaskTextWatcher(percentual, simpleMaskPercentual);
        percentual.addTextChangedListener( maskPercentual );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double percent sign `%%`. For further details please go to [Show percentage in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708444/java-literal-percent-sign-in-printf-statement)